# Python - Ported AS2 function doesn't work

Tags: python

This game uses this encryption to stop people from being able to connect bots easily the function used by the game is:

```
function djinndecrypt(string, key) {
    var crypt = "";
    var part = "";
    var parts = 0;
    var keyGen = key.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var char = string.charAt(i);
        var chrNum = string.charCodeAt(i);
        var keyChr = key.charAt(parts % key.length);
        var keyNum = key.charCodeAt(parts % key.length);
        part += char;
        if((i+1) % 3 == 0 && i > 0) {
            crypt += String.fromCharCode((coreHash.indexOf(part)+2) - keyNum - keyGen);
            part = "";
            parts++;
        }
    }
    return crypt;
```

I have attempted to port this to python my code is:

```
coreHash = "4Qiqc3mpjw2jFLJBaV9ANsWoYDR8ktvZIMeJTfOd1lyH5P7XKxhU6rCbzuE10nS5Ks7rPj1YvnDlbX4m2jI0NkyOL3hHU6FRVduJJoCwfWiABzqSaETMet1pZ89xQc81ieHA0F5EuNnWCwJvMJLQhV3UxPYRB76pbfIy2dcoaT14XkqlZsSzj9KDtrmjO9fjdMPERB12TYzDJrNxc3QajKU0kbvu4F56yHAXWO7tlwni8mZqCSosLVIehJ1pzT1kEsSXAl1O45CdLnRwQeM06ZqxJfJayBN8FWj2prYjuKIhiHU7VbomDPvct935yULcOHNJZsa31DeSlmnPBxJkYbTdAFRotIizv2VpXuf9w0KqQ8Ehjr4MW7Cj164Y1ukWxp9EjOwDPF8rsX5vlZN7QJqfteCATKncUoLVaM16Shy";

def djinndecrypt(string, key):
    crypt = ""
    part = ""
    parts = 0;
    keyGen = len(key)

    for i in xrange(len(string)):
        char = string[i]
        chrNum = ord(char)
        keyChr = key[parts % len(key)]
        keyNum = ord(keyChr)
        part += char

        if((i + 1) % 3 == 0 and i > 0):
            crypt += chr((coreHash.find(part) + 2) - keyNum - keyGen)
            part = ""
            parts += 1

    print crypt

djinndecrypt("zQDHzljoHM6RhuhuhWzQDA5dgOAzQDlbAqkgOA57mM", "69338277581336797325449966279465")
```

The code ends up raising an exception:

```
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[chr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) only accepts up to 255 as described by the error. You can get more distance using [unichr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr) but that returns Unicode characters instead of ACSII like chr().

However, given that this is supposed to result in an English string, the problem appears to be in the coreHash, as results above 122 [ chr(122) is 'z' ] will be out of alphabetical range.

Comment: ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)

Comment: You are, correct me if I'm wrong: grabbing an index, at which the 3 digit section of the original, can be found in the Core +/- the Key. As a way to get an English string.

So the problem is probably inside the CoreHash. Because receiving inputs for chr larger than 122 will already be out of alphabetical range.

Comment: It turned out the game had update their coreHash and changed a few functions, thanks.